# Create an responsive design menu with JSF and PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a menu with PrimeFaces and JSF like [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/panelMenu.xhtml) one.

Since i don't know how many items i'm gonne have, this menu has to be dynamically. At runtime i will get an `array` of `StudentsGroup-Objects`. Every `StudentsGroup-Object` contains several `Students-Objects`. Also it should be an `responsive design`. Is that possible with PrimeFaces? How do i achieve this?

It should look somthing like this
[image]

I didn't find any tutorial which explains somthing like this. It would be enough if someone could post a goot tutorial.

Comment: Something like what? Making such a menu 'responsive'? Then start by telling how it should be responsive? And by posting a 'good' tutorial you mean a complete solution?

Comment: The image shows the kind of menu i try to achieve. At best the menu should have an responsive design. Doesn't need to be a complete solution, it would be enough if someone could link an tutorial which could help me or lead me in the right direction.

Comment: What is responsive in this menu? Should it be horizontal in big screens? Should it hide an show a button on smaller screens? What?

Comment: Right now it has a fix size like "width:300px". It would be enough if the width changes when the screen gets smaller. Right now im struggling to create this menu dynamically since i don't know how many objects im gonna have

Comment: Give it a styleClass and see what media queries in css can do for you

Answer (score 2):

Prime faces doesn't seem to have built-in responsive functionality for it's menu item, however, you should be able to apply CSS style-sheets to your elements and design your own responsive layouts.

If you're looking for a tutorial, finding a tutorial on how to do this, specifically, is what you're looking for, not a tutorial that's specific to Prime Faces.

Answer (score 1):

Tutorial:

1. Add a button/image/link in front of the menu
2. Create css with media queries that hide the menu on small screens and show the button
3. Add javascript to the button/image/link that when clicked on

   1. shows the menu by changing css (adding classs or whatever
   2. Add an '#' entry to the history so the back button closes the menu
   3. Add an onclick event handler to the body to hide the menu if clicked outside (remove it when actually activated)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Primefaces Themes they provide

-> there are showcases:
http://www.primefaces.org/sentinel/

-> and if you are nice bye it:
http://www.primefaces.org/layouts/sentinel